# Spatial similarity between polygons

Tags: python, postgis, polygon, spatial-analyst, database

I am using PostGIS and python3. I have a table with polygons objects, the polygons have year as an attribute. I need to identify the uniqueness of the polygons trough time. For instance I need to identify if polygon x from year y is most likely to be which polygon in another year. I realize that this is not an easy question, but any help or thought is more than welcome. I though on doing it by the percentage of interception for instance, but I am ot sure if it is the best analysis.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! For polygon equality, you can look at the Boundless Postgis introduction : https://www.postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/equality.html.

Comment: Thanks I did not know those functions of PostGIS.!

Comment: I thing, this is exactly what you are looking for... https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html or https://postgis.net/docs/ST_FrechetDistance.html